# Count occurences in multiple array json with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json that return the structure below.
I need to count item_name occurrence and print the information like:

```
<li>nameX(locationX) = 3</li>
<li>nameY(locationY) = 1</li>
```

I tried with array_count_values but it's not work with multiple arrays and specific item to count like "item_name", the item_location is the same of item_name and it's not necessary to count, only take the value once.

```
[
{
    0 : {
        item: {
            item_basic: {
                item_country: {
                    other_item: not important
                    item_name: nameX
                    other_item01: not important
                    item_location: locationX
                    other_item02: not important
                }
            }
        }
    }
    1 : {
        item: {
            item_basic: {
                item_country: {
                    other_item: not important
                    item_name: nameX
                    other_item01: not important
                    item_location: locationX
                    other_item02: not important
                }
            }
        }
    }
    2 : {
        item: {
            item_basic: {
                item_country: {
                    other_item: not important
                    item_name: nameY
                    other_item01: not important
                    item_location: locationY
                    other_item02: not important
                }
            }
        }
    }
    3 : {
        item: {
            item_basic: {
                item_country: {
                    other_item: not important
                    item_name: nameX
                    other_item01: not important
                    item_location: locationX
                    other_item02: not important
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: _the item_location is the same of item_name and it's not necessary to count, only take the value once._ -  Your `<li>` tags example you provided only count to 3 when there is actually 4 `item_name`s with nameX and with nameY... I'm assuming you mean if the item_name and item_location do not match you do not want to count them?

Comment: @MinistryofChaps sorry about that I change the li to 3, yes, the item_name and item_location match in all arrays.  for example
if item_name = nameX the item_location will be locationX
if item_name = nameY the item_location will be locationY

Comment: @Darinif okay good to know, could you provide your attempt of how your tried this, please.

Comment: @Darinif also in your example, the last array's item_name and item_location do not match.

Comment: I tried this example but it's only work with one array: 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count_values.asp

Comment: @Darinif does the below answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution would be to use a foreach loop that gathers the `item_name` value from each array and place the values in a separate array. Then use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) on the array you put the values in.

Here is a working solution:

```
<?php

 $JSON = '{
  "0": {
    "item": {
      "item_basic": {
        "item_country": {
          "other_item": "not important",
          "item_name": "nameX",
          "other_item01": "not important",
          "item_location": "locationX",
          "other_item02": "not important"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "item": {
      "item_basic": {
        "item_country": {
          "other_item": "not important",
          "item_name": "nameX",
          "other_item01": "not important",
          "item_location": "locationX",
          "other_item02": "not important"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "item": {
      "item_basic": {
        "item_country": {
          "other_item": "not important",
          "item_name": "nameY",
          "other_item01": "not important",
          "item_location": "locationY",
          "other_item02": "not important"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "item": {
      "item_basic": {
        "item_country": {
          "other_item": "not important",
          "item_name": "nameY",
          "other_item01": "not important",
          "item_location": "locationY",
          "other_item02": "not important"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}';

 $JSON = json_decode($JSON, TRUE);
 $item_names = array();
 foreach ($JSON as $item)
     {
     array_push($item_names, $item['item']['item_basic']['item_country']['item_name']);
     }

     $items_counted = array_count_values($item_names);



print_r($items_counted);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [nameX] => 2 [nameY] => 2 )
```

Also, [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) states it only works for one array:

> array_count_values — Counts all the values of an array